# vector spaces whose algebra of endomorphisms is generated by its idempotents

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space whose algebra of endomorphisms is generated (as a $K$-algebra) by its idempotents.

Is $V$ necessarily finite dimensional?

**EDIT** (Jul 26 '14) A closely related question:

Is there a field $K$ and a $K$-vector space whose algebra of endomorphisms of is **not** generated (as a $K$-algebra) by its idempotents?

Comment: In the infinite dimensional case are you interested just in vector spaces and arbitrary linear maps or something more restrictive?

Comment: @JHance - Yes, in the infinite dimensional case, I'm interested just in vector spaces and arbitrary linear maps.

Comment: So we want to consider $\mathscr L(V)$, the algebra of $K$-linear maps from $V$ to $V$, is that right?  By the way, hella nice question, +1!

Comment: @RobertLewis - Dear Robert, yes, we want to consider the algebra of all $K$-linear maps from $V$ to $V$. Thanks for your kind words and your vote!

Comment: Another closely related question to which I don't know the answer: Is there a field K and a K-vector space whose algebra of endomorphisms is not generated as a K-vector space by its idempotents?

Comment: @JonasMeyer - Dear Jonas: I don't know the answer either. I hadn't thought of that. It might be a more natural question. Please feel free to edit. - Another thing I don't know, is how to thank you for your comment and your bounty!

Comment: @JonasMeyer - Dear Jonas: My suggestion (for what it's worth) is that you ask a separate question with your statement. - To the other readers: you may want to take a look at this meta post: [Congrats and Thanks to Jonas Meyer!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16314/660)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard - Dear Pierre-Yves: Thank you. Perhaps I will, but if so I will wait a while first, because an answer to your question(s) might answer or at least shed more light on that question.

Comment: @JonasMeyer - Dear Jonas: This is just to tell you that I posted a new answer.

Comment: @JonasMeyer - Dear Jonas: Please take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/886864/660).

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard - I have shamelessly filched your idea of exploiting the isomorphism $\mathrm{End}(V)\cong\mathbb{M}_2(\mathrm{End}(V))$ for $V$ infinite-dimensional. Check [More classes of rings spanned by units?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889890/more-classes-of-rings-spanned-by-units).

Comment: @1947chizek - Thanks! I had noticed your question, seen its link to this one, and was the first one to vote for it! Actually, it was George's idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The algebra of endomorphisms of any vector space $V$ is generated by the idempotents.

The finite dimensional case is straightforward, so I will suppose that $V$ is infinite dimensional. Then (assuming the axiom of choice), we have $V\cong W\oplus W$ for some vector space $W$. In fact, we can take $W=V$, as a vector space is determined up to isomorphism by its dimension and, using the fact that $\kappa+\kappa=\kappa$ for infinite cardinals $\kappa$, we have
$$
\mathop{dim}(V\oplus V)=\mathop{dim}V+\mathop{dim}V=\mathop{dim}V.
$$
So, $V\cong V\oplus V$.

Writing $V\cong W\oplus W$, the endomorphisms of $V$ can be identified with the algebra $M_2(\mathrm{End}(W))$ of $2\times2$ matrices over the endomorphism ring of $W$. We can now express any element of this ring explicitly in terms of idempotents,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\matrix{a&b\\c&d}\right)&=\left(\matrix{a-1&0\\0&0}\right)+\left(\matrix{1&b\\0&0}\right)+\left(\matrix{0&0\\c&1}\right)+\left(\matrix{0&0\\0&d-1}\right)\\ \\
&=\left(\matrix{1&a-2\\0&0}\right)\left(\matrix{1&0\\1&0}\right)+\left(\matrix{1&b\\0&0}\right)\\
&+\left(\matrix{0&0\\c&1}\right)+\left(\matrix{0&0\\1&d-2}\right)\left(\matrix{0&1\\0&1}\right).
\end{align}
$$
[Edit: I replaced the rhs with Pierre-Yves' much simpler variant]. It can be checked that all the matrices on the right hand side of the final equality are idempotents.

Comment: Dear George: Thank you very much for your wonderful answer! I just posted a minor variant.

Comment: Comment for George, Jonas, and everybody else: George shows that any endomorphism is a linear combination of length 3 words in the idempotents, prompting the question: is 3 the best constant? Letting $c=c(K,V)$ be  the best constant, we have the trichotomy: $c=1,c=2$ or $c=3$. Jonas asked (in his first comment to the question): is $c$ always equal to 1?

Comment: Thanks. The variant is a bit cleaner - maybe I should replace the rhs of my identity with that?

Comment: I have a slight preference in favour of the replacement you suggest...

Comment: Continuation of the previous comment. In fact George shows that any matrix in $M_2(R)$, for any ring $R$, is a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of length 3 words in the idempotents of $M_2(R)$. So, we can ask the same question as before with $c(R)$ instead of $c(K,V)$. (Here *ring* means *associative ring with 1*.)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: The answer to the last question is no. In the case where $R$ is an integral domain then, if $M\in M_2(R)$ is idempotent then you either have $M$ being diagonal with idempotent components or $\mathrm{trace}(M)=1$. In any case, $\mathrm{trace}(M)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of idempotents. A positive answer to the question would imply that every element of $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of idempotents in $R$ (and, $0,1$ are the only idempotents). This fails in all integral domains except for quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, you proved that, assuming $R$ is an integral domain, but not a quotient of $\mathbb Z$, we have $c(R)=2$ or $c(R)=3$. - Also, it would perhaps be more natural to suppose that $R$ is an algebra over some commutative ring $K$, and to consider $K$-linear combinations (instead of restricting to the case $K=\mathbb Z$). - I feel that the statement you prove in your answer is much stronger than what was required, so I'm trying to imagine further developments...

Comment: It's perhaps worth saying it explicitly: George's identity holds in $M_2(\mathbb Z\langle a,b,c,d\rangle)$, where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are indeterminates, and $\mathbb Z\langle a,b,c,d\rangle$ is the free ring generated by $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Comment: Dear George: This is just to tell you that I posted a new answer.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Thanks. I see you came up with an even cleaner variant. Mind if I adapt my answer to use it? Also, I can give a proof of Jonas Meyer's question. Every endomorphism of a vector space is a linear combination of idempotents.

Comment: Dear George: Please feel free to adapt your answer to use my variant. I asked Jonas's question separately: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/886864/660. You can guess how anxious I am to see your answer!

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of this post is to prove:

> (a) If $R$ is a ring (*i.e.* an associative ring with $1$), then any two by two matrix with entries in $R$ is a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of products of *two* idempotents.

Proof: We have

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&a-1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1&b+1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\\ \\ 
&+\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ d-1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ c+1&0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

QED

George Lowther proved:

> (b) If $R$ is a ring, then any two by two matrix with entries in $R$ is a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of products of *three* idempotents.

George also explained that, in order to answer the question, it sufficed to prove:

> (c) If $R$ is a ring, then any two by two matrix with entries in $R$ is a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of products of idempotents.

Going from (b) to (a) reduces the number of factors from three down to two. This number *cannot* be reduced further, because, as George observed in a comment, a two by two matrix with entries in $R$ is **not** in general a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of idempotents.

Indeed, for trace reasons, 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
is **not** a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of idempotents of $M_2(\mathbb Q)$.

In fact George shows that, if $R$ is a domain, then the condition that any two by two matrix with entries in $R$ is a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of idempotents is equivalent to $R$ being a quotient of $\mathbb Z$.

The question about the least number of factors was raised by Jonas Meyer in a comment. Things will become clearer if we generalize slightly the setting.

Let $K$ be a commutative ring and $R$ a $K$-algebra (associative with $1$).

By our previous considerations, any two by two matrix with entries in $R$ is a $K$-linear combination of products of two idempotents, but in general not a $K$-linear combination of idempotents.

Say that $R$ is $K$-**nice**, or **nice over** $K$, if any two by two matrix with entries in $R$ *is* a $K$-linear combination idempotents.

Jonas asked if $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ (for $V$ a $K$-vector space) is $K$-nice.

One can also ask which rings are nice over their center.

In view of the above proof, $R$ is $K$-nice if and only if any matrix of the form 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
is a $K$-linear combination of idempotents.