# Sum of two units cannot be a unit in a ring of integers.

Tags: number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. Then is it true that $1+u$ is a non-unit for every $u\in\mathcal{O}_K^*$? I believe this is true. I have worked out a few examples and in each one of them this holds. But I cannot find a general proof anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your title says "ring" but your question says "field".

Comment: K is a field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ is its ring of integers, where $1+u$ lies.

Comment: Also do you mean a finite field.  Because the integers don't form a field.

Comment: Of course not. A number field is never finite. I think you are misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @QthePlatypus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers

Comment: Hint for a counterexample: consider roots of unity.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, you are right. In $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ this is not true. Is there a characterization of such typical ring of integers? This holds for all $K$'s such that $\mathbb{O}_K^*=\{\pm 1\}$ and also when $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: Generalizing the example with third/sixth roots of unity a little bit: Whenever $u$ satisfies an equation of the form $1+u=\pm u^n$ it follows that $u$ is a unit of  the ring of integers of some field. And obviously so is $1+u$. Further generalizations can be cooked up.

Comment: The other extreme - the sum of two units is always a unit (or 0) - is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30556/242) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/912647/242).