# Group ring of the ring generated by the trivial units of a group ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

The trivial units of a group ring form a group.

A group ring is a construction that combines a group and a ring. Given a group $G$ and a ring $R$, the group ring of $G$ over $R$, denoted as $R[G]$, is the set of all finite formal linear combinations of elements of $G$ with coefficients from $R$. The elements of $R[G]$ are typically expressed as sums of the form $\sum {r_ig_i}$ where $r_i$ are elements of $R$ and $g_i$ are elements of $G$.

The trivial units of $R[G]$ are the elements that can be expressed as a product of a unit in R and an element in $G$. This set is denoted as $U(R)G$, where $U(R)$ represents the group of units in the ring $R$.

To show that $U(R)G$ forms a group, we need to verify the group axioms:

Closure: For any two trivial units $u = rg$ and $v = sh$ in $U(R)$, their product $uv$ is also a trivial unit. This is true because the product is given by $(rg)(sh)$ = $(rs)(gh)$, where $rs$ and $gh$ are units in $R$and elements in $G$, respectively.

Associativity: The product of trivial units is associative, following the associativity of the ring $R$ and the group $G$.

Identity: The identity element in $U(R)G$ is the trivial unit $1$, where $1 = 1_G$ is the identity element of the group $G$.

Inverses: For each trivial unit $u = rg$ in $U(R)G$, its inverse is given by $u^{-1} = (r^{-1})(g^{-1})$, where $r^{-1}$ is the inverse of $r$ in $R$ and $g^{-1}$ is the inverse of $g$ in $G$. Since both $r^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ exist in their respective groups, the inverse $u^{-1}$ is also a trivial unit.

Therefore, the set of trivial units $U(R)G$ forms a group under multiplication.

But $U(R)G$ is a set, it is not a ring. It is not a group ring. It is a group. It is isomorphic to $U(R)\times G$ as a group.

The isomorphism can be defined as follows: For any element $u = rg$ in $U(R)G$, where $r$ is a unit in $R$ and $g$ is an element in $G$, we can map $u$ to the pair $(r, g)$ in $U(R) × G$ This mapping is a bijective homomorphism, and under this isomorphism, the group operations in $U(R)G$ and $U(R) × G$ correspond.

However, for a generic group ring $R[G]$, I wonder what can be said about the group ring $T[G]$, where $T$ is the subring of $R$ generated by the group $U(R)$ (formed by closing $U(R)$under addition).

Thanks.

Comment: Please use MathJax, this is too hard to read. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Another common notation for what you call $U(R)$ is $R^\times$. Group rings are a red herring; your question seems like it's really about the subring of $R$ generated by $R^\times$.

Comment: The entire question is contained in your last parapgraph, right? I know that people ask for context and other meaningless things not to close questions… but here we could delete 97.12% of the text.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. What is a red herring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some older work which studies rings that are generated by their groups of units, like [this MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889890/more-classes-of-rings-spanned-by-units) or R. Raphael, *Rings Which Are Generated by Their Units*, J. of Algebra **28**, 199-205 (1974). In your situation, this means studying when the ring you wrote $T$ coincides with $R$, and of course does not involve your group $G$, which actually does not really play any role in your question. Beware that these two references us a different and more standard notation than yours, though.

Comment: It is really a bad idea to answer the question using U(R) to mean a completely different thing that what the original posted used it for in the question itself… Specially when you did not do anything with it! A good 50% of what you wrote consist of saying that you will use the notation to mean something different :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ...this sort of thing is why I stopped hanging out here and answering questions. It's just plain unwelcoming. Feel free to edit my answer if you wish. Raphael uses $U(R)$, which is why I picked it.

Comment: Sorry if I have bothered you, and thank you for your answers. I am new to reading articles online outside of Stack Exchange. Can someone please give me complete instructions on how to view the article by R. Raphael, Rings Which Are Generated by Their Units, J. of Algebra 28, 199-205 (1974)? Do I need to pay or be located in a given county or be located on a university campus and perhaps pay a fee to read the article? I have tried downloading it in chrome, but can't figure out where the download goes. Can someone please give me more steps on how to access this material? Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you could simply view the material within the chrome web browser on your Android phone, which reflects my situation. Thanks.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson Hmm, troubleshooting browser issues is beyond the scope of MSE, but you might try clicking the vertical dots and going to Downloads. Alternatively, use another machine. The [Raphael paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869374900325) appears to be freely available, I would imagine regardless of your region or affiliation. Good luck.